# Decodificar json desde php enviado por jquery.ajax(POST) Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, json, wordpress, email

Tengo un json que esta almacenada en la variable **proyectos** el cual es enviado por jquery.ajax de e esta manera:

```
  var proyectos = [{"Paso1": selectEmpStar},{"Paso2": selectEtapa},{"Paso3": selectServ},{"Paso4": selectCarac},{"Paso5": selectCuent},{"Paso6": selecDatos}];
```

Enviando por post el json

```
  var datos = JSON.stringify(proyectos);
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url:'<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>',
    data:{ 
    action: 'contact_send',
    dataProyectos : datos,
    dataAsunto : valNombres
    },
    success: function() {
        alert("Mensaje Enviado");
    }
  });
```

y en el php de wordpress para el envío de correo:

```
function callback_contact_send() {
$send_to = 'ejemplo@hotmail.com';
$subject = $_POST['dataAsunto'];
$message = $_POST['dataProyectos'];
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: proyectos-tecnologicos' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$mail = mail($send_to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if($mail){
  echo "Mensaje enviado";
}else{
  echo "Error";
}
die();
```

}

El mensaje llega correctamente pero de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De que manera podría formatear el json y que no llegue de esa manera para una mejor visualización?

Comment: Usa `json_decode($_POST['dataProyectos']);` de esta forma lo podras trabajar

Comment: De que manera podría trabajarlo ? un ejemplo ? porfavor

Comment: La forma que estás generando el JSON lo hace incómodo para procesar. Si pudieses modificar el formato, te sería más sencillo. Por ejemplo: `[selectEmpStar,selectEtapa,etc]` ... o `{"Paso1":selectEmpStar,"Paso2":selectEtapa,"Paso3":etc}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decodificas el json en un objeto:

```
$datos=json_decode($_POST['dataProyectos']);
```

acceder a los valores del objeto `$datos`

```
$mensaje="Empresa ".$datos->Paso1->empresa."<br>";
$mensaje.="Etapa ".$datos->Paso2->etapa."<br>";
 /***DEMAS CODIGO***/
```

**EDITO**

Mariano tiene razón hice la prueba y no va ha funcionar te recomiendo modificar la estructura de tu JSON para que sea mas manejable ejemplo

`"{\"Paso1\":{\"empresa\":\"startup\"},\"Paso2\":\"etapa\":\"Tengo una idea\"}}"`

De esta forma puedes manejarlo con el ejemplo inicial

Comment: Ojo que el JSON que recibe es un array de objetos

Comment: Lo que te comentaba era para cambiarlo a `$datos[0]->Paso1->empresa`, `$datos[1]->Paso2->etapa`, etc. ;-) ... Pero sí, si puede cambiar el origen, sería mucho más cómodo

Comment: ¡Ho! no sabia que se podia manejar asi.

Comment: Simplemente es un array por eso el JSON empieza con `[`, en el que cada elemento del array es un objeto con sus propiedades (y el valor de la propiedad `PasoN` es otro objeto)

Comment: Muchas gracias ambos! en realidad que me han ayudado y ahora lo tengo en este formato :

{"paso1": selectEmpStar, "paso2": selectEtapa, "paso3": selectServ, "paso4": selectCarac, "paso5": selectCuent, "paso6": selecDatos}
que esta mas simple de manejar pero por ejemplo cada valor que esta en cada paso(selectEMptStart, selectEtapa, etc) es un arreglo que contiene varios valores. Diciendo esto como lo manejaria en el php?

Comment: Ya que en cada selectEmpStart, selectEtapa, etc tiene sus nombres propios para cada valor almacenado por ejemplo el de selectCuent tiene por dentro -> selectCuent.push({"TiempoProyecto": valCuent1});  y        selectCuent.push({"Cuentanos": valCuent});
O sea como accedo desde el php a estos?

Answer (score 0):

Si el mensaje es html, añade las etiquetas "pre" delante y detrás del body:

```
$message = "<pre>" . $_POST['dataProyectos'] . "</pre>";
```